# maven-surefire-plugin how to rerun failed TestNG tests? There is default rerun option for JUnit only

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

How can I run the failed TestNG tests with maven failsafe plugin?
I run my tests with 'mvn clean install'.
When I run the tests and I get failing tests, I need to rerun them.
I do not have a testng.xml file and I think that this is also an issue.

This my pom.xml

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <configuration>
            <parallel>methods</parallel>
            <threadCount>${threads}</threadCount>
            <systemProperties>
                <browser>${browser}</browser>
                <screenshotDirectory>${project.build.directory}/screenshots</screenshotDirectory>
                <remoteDriver>${remote}</remoteDriver>
                <gridURL>${seleniumGridURL}</gridURL>
                <desiredPlatform>${platform}</desiredPlatform>

                <desiredBrowserVersion>${browserVersion}</desiredBrowserVersion>             <!--Set properties passed in by the driver binary              downloader-->
                <!--Set properties passed in by the driver binary downloader-->
                <phantomjs.binary.path>${phantomjs.binary.path}</phantomjs.binary.path>
                <webdriver.chrome.driver>${webdriver.chrome.driver}</webdriver.chrome.driver>
                <webdriver.ie.driver>${webdriver.ie.driver}</webdriver.ie.driver>
                <webdriver.opera.driver>${webdriver.opera.driver}</webdriver.opera.driver>
            </systemProperties>
            <includes>
                <!-- All that is left now is to clean up the code in our basicTest class and change its name to BasicTestWD. You may have noticed that we added an <includes> configuration item to our POM. This is because Maven will use maven-surefireplugin to run files that have test at the start or end of their name. We don't want maven-surefire-plugin to pick up our tests; we want to use maven-failsafeplugin instead. -->
                <include>**/*WD.java</include>
            </includes>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>com.lazerycode.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>driver-binary-downloader-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.7</version>
        <configuration>
            <rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
                ${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/selenium_standalone_binaries
            </rootStandaloneServerDirectory>
            <downloadedZipFileDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/selenium_standalone_zips
            </downloadedZipFileDirectory>
            <customRepositoryMap>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/RepositoryMap.xml
            </customRepositoryMap>
            <overwriteFilesThatExist>${overwrite.binaries}</overwriteFilesThatExist>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>selenium</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. When you do a build (with mvn clean install), then you compile your code and run _all_ the unit and integration tests. When an integration test fails, you usually have to change your code (or make sure that the external resources that your need for the test are present). Then you run the build again (mvn clean install). It is usually advisable to run all the tests again. If, though, you want to experiment, it is better to call the tests from your IDE to get fast feedback.

Comment: To clarify: I have flaky failing ui tests due to a slow server responses and my build fails intermittently.

Comment: It is not really useful to have unreliable tests in your build. If you call the productive, real servers and they are too slow, that is a problem that needs to be fixed because your users will experience the same. If the servers are for tests only, they either need to be fixed or replaced by some simulation that answers reliably. If you cannot change anything about the servers or how they are called, remove the tests from your build and start them manually after your build to watch the responses.